# Ruby On Rails - best way to implement Tinder behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am building a Rails Api for a mobile client that works almost the same way as Tinder. The mobile users will receive some images and will like, dislike or give a neutral mark to the image.

I'd like to know what is the best way to implement such a system knowing that if user X receives an image Y(then gave it a like, a dislike or a neutral mark), how to make sure he/she won't receive the same image.

I am looking for a powerful technique or model that will enhance my server performances.

FYI, I currently have 10K users and 100K images. so it is very important to make sur performance stay quiet good.

I am using Ruby-on-Rails 4 and Postgresql.

Comment: How are you saving the value for the user choice? Can't you just check for the existence of the record or the existence of like/dislike/neutral before showing an image?

Comment: I was thinking of adding a column to my Image model where it will hold all users ids that liked, dislked or gave a neutral mark to the image. This column would be an array of strings(something which is possible with postgres).

Comment: parsing that string will get slow really quickly. I think a join table would be better. I'll add an answer re: what I'm thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 class ViewedImage
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :image
 end

 class User
   has_many :viewed_images
   has_many :images, through: :viewed_images
 end

 class Image
   has_many :viewed_images
   has_many :users, through: :viewed_images
 end
```

Create a ViewedImage whenever someone takes an action on an image and save the user_id and the image_id on the ViewedImage record. Then look to see if the current image has a record for that user_id / image_id.

Comment: This is one of the solutions I've tought about. 
Let's say I have an image that was viewed 1000 times, I'll have 1000 ViewedImage record associated to this image. Say also I have about 1 millions ViewedImage record and I have an index on image_id, I think it would be better if I store user ids that viewed the image in array(which is  a column that belongs to Image)... What do you think?

Comment: @OmarLahlou It's still going to be much faster to look up that record with both of those foreign key references than it will be to parse a string of 1000s ids and then iterate through it to find the user.

Comment: you could benchmark both approaches, though to be sure. I feel pretty confident that iterating through an array of the ids, one by one, can't be faster but I'm wrong about things on a daily basis so benchmarking it is a good approach. You could also start w/ the string and then create the records lately if you decide to switch approaches...although the inverse is true as well. Not that hard to change.